# java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed during weblogic 12.2 startup after application deployment

Tags: deployment, weblogic, devops, weblogic12c, mbeans

I'm getting the below exception during weblogic server startup. Java version used: 1.8.
The jar file in the exception is in the correct directory and that class file CdrCircuitResponse is present in that jar.

```
<

Apr 20, 2020 7:23:37,775 AM EDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "action" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "abcfca.war".
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/apps/opt/Domain1/abcfca/jars/abcfcaService.jar!/com/org/abcfca/response/dto/CdrCircuitResponse.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:272)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1410)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug from WLS:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2384506_1.html

Please apply the patch and let us know

Comment: Link dead. Can you add the info in your answer?

Comment: In the end, the classloader helper that open the jar/zip file has been closed.